# View of ListView can not inflate Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, layout, android-listview

I am trying to create an adapter for my listview and I am getting an error on the getview() and specifically on the View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_results, parent, false); THANKS.

The error says activity_results cannot be resolved or is not a field

```
public class testadapter extends BaseAdapter
{
   Context context;
    String[] question;
    String[] answer;

    LayoutInflater inflater;


public testadapter(Context context, String[] question, String[] answer) {
    this.context = context;
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return question.length;
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView txtViewTitle;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtquestion;

    TextView txtanswer;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_results, parent, false);

    txtquestion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);



    txtanswer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);

    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    txtquestion.setText(question[position]);
    txtanswer.setText(answer[position]);

    return itemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your xml file too

Comment: In your code, you have a comment saying: "Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml" but you're inflating `activity_results`? Is that part of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check that `activity_results.xml` exists in the specific layout folder for the resolution you are running your code. May be you need to copy this xml in your other layout folders.

You need to check `Supporting Different Screens in Android` - http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.htmlhttp://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Re-generating R file might solve the problem.

1. Right click on the project in File Explorer.
2. Select "Clean project"
3. Confirm clean operation.

Goto Project menu, see if "Build Automatically" option is checked. Uncheck it.
Right click on the project in File Explorer and select "Build"

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way hope this demo help you....

1. Main Xml file for holding "ListView" (activity_main.xml)
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

2. ListItem Xml file for holding "ListView" Items (list_item.xml).
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtQns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

3. Activity (MainActivity)
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lstMain;
    private MyCustomAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lstMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstMain);

        String[] questionArray = new String[]{"Qun-1","Qun-2","Qun-3","Qun-4","Qun-5"};
        String[] answerArray = new String[]{"Ans-1","Ans-2","Ans-3","Ans-4","Ans-5"};

        // set adapter dara
        adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,questionArray,answerArray);
        lstMain.setAdapter(adapter);

        lstMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
                try{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,adapter.getItem(pos).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        Context context;
        String[] question;
        String[] answer;


        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, String[] question, String[] answer) {
            this.context = context;
            this.question = question;
            this.answer = answer;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return question.length;
        }


        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return question[position]+"\n"+answer[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }



        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,null,false);
                holder.txtQuestion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQns);
                holder.txtAnswer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAns);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            // Capture position and set to the TextViews
            holder.txtQuestion.setText(question[position]);
            holder.txtAnswer.setText(answer[position]);

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView txtQuestion;
        public TextView txtAnswer;
    }

}
```